# ClassNotFoundException on attempt to start docker image created from layered war

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

There was a request to [support layered war creation with Gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22195).

As I can see from [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#layered-wars), it should be supported since Spring Boot 2.5.

I try to create simplest example app possible using https://start.spring.io/: Gradle project with War packaging:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
  id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And the following Dockerfile initially taken from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html/features.html#features.container-images.building.dockerfiles) with `jar` file extension replaced to `war`:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.war
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.war
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.war extract

FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

The problem is that with war-packaging on attempt to run created docker-image I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.layered.LayeredApplication
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:135)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Removing war plugin from `build.gradle` solved the problem, but to additionally support deployment on particular Tomcat I need war-packaging of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to the problem while was reviewing my question. Decided to leave the question/answer for anyone else facing the problem in the future.

It turned out that if I want to dockerize layered **war**, I need to change `JarLauncher` to `WarLauncher` in Dockerfile's `ENTRYPOINT`.